# how to draw 4*4 grid with 1:1 resolution in ionic camera?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am trying to open camera with 4X4 grid enabled. All I can do is open native camera application with some camera options which doesn't include options for grid. Since I am using native camera application, I'm manually enabling the grid from the settings. I don't want to do that. Is there anything else I can do for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Bruce, can you share example of such grid? is that an overlay?